# Get element from string between 2 symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having string like this:

`Adress 22 - 99, world`

I need to get value `99` from this string, witch is between `-` and `,` symbols. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Adress 22 - 99, world"[/(?<=-[\s*])(.*)(?=,)/]
# 99
```

There can be for sure a better regex, but this fits the example given. Gets everything between a "-" followed by 0 or more whitespaces and ",".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i'm getting error like this `compile error
path/to/file: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=-[\s*])(.*)(?=,)/` Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know your Ruby version.

Comment: That's my fault! Forgot to write that.

Comment: I can't come up with anything else than using split `"Jura Alunana 11 - 126, Riga".split(" - ")[-1].split(",")[0]`.

Comment: The character class `[\s*]` matches a whitespace or an asterisk. I don't think that's what you want. Note that, in the OP's example, the comma immediately follows the digits to be extracted, but the question does not specify that there are no intervening characters (or that there is exactly one space--or even no characters other than spaces--between the comma and the digits to be extracted).

Answer (score 2):

Try using gsub:

```
str = "Jura Alunana 11 - 126, Riga"
value = str.gsub(/.*- (\d+),.*/, '\1') # \1 means the digits inside the first ( ) pair
#  => "126"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working too, but number can be with letter too, like `5A`, `126B` and so on. This gsub is ignoring it. But thank you for your time!

Comment: @Marshmello then, you need to replace `(\d+)` with `([\d|[a-z]]+)`, so the final result is `/.*- ([\d|[a-z]]+),.*/i`. But this is a correct answer. Check this Rubular link https://rubular.com/r/vl4SR1wOVq479v

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Jura Alunana 11 - 126, Riga"
```

```
r = /.*-\D*\K\d+(?=.*,)/
```

```
str[r]
  #=> "126"
```

```
str1 = "Jura Alunana 11 - cat 126 ahem 33 , Riga"
str1[r]
  #=> "126"
```

We can make the regular expression self-documenting by defining it in free-spacing mode:

```
r = /
    .*       # match 0+ characters
    -\D*     # match a hyphen followed by 0+ non-digits
    \K       # forget everything matched so far
    \d+      # match 1+ digits...
    (?=.*,)  # ...followed by 0+ characters then a comma (positive lookahead) 
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Alternatively,

```
r = /
    .*-\D* # match 0+ characters, a hyphen then 0+ non-digits
    (\d+)  # match 1+ digits in capture group 1
    .*,    # match 0+ characters then a comma
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
str[r, 1]
  #=> "126"
str1[r, 1]
  #=> "126"
```

Comment: Why we should use `1`? What does it means? :)

Comment: @Marshmello, see [String#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), specifically the form of the method `str[regexp, capture]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take.  I find it a bit easier to read than some of the other solutions.

```
str = "Jura Alunana 11 - 126, Riga"
str.match(/-\s(\d+),/)
puts $1

# => 126
```